# Lodash reduce array of objects from array of objects

Tags: lodash, reduce

I'm trying to get a list of all guideScenes in all sections via

```
let combinedScenes = _.reduce(sections,
  (prev, section) =>  {return {...prev, ...section.guideScenes}},
  {}
)
```

It's only returning the first section list, how do I get all of them in there?

Comment: Please update the question with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const sections = [{guideScenes: ['hello']}, {guideScenes: ['world']}, {guideScenes: ['hi', 'yo']}] 

let combinedScenesObj = _.reduce(sections, (prev, section, index) =>  {
  return {...prev, [index]: [...section.guideScenes]}
}, {})

console.log('object:', combinedScenesObj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

You were close you needed a key to be added to each array because you were trying to add to an object

```
//dummy data
const sections = [{guideScenes: ['hello']}, {guideScenes: ['world']}, {guideScenes: ['hi', 'yo']}]
```

if you're wanting to resolve to an object you should give the item a key, for instance, I've used the index in this example

```
let combinedScenesObj = _.reduce(sections, (prev, section, index) =>  {
  return {...prev, [index]:[...section.guideScenes]};
}, {})
// { 0: ["hello"], 1: ["world"], 2: ["hi", "yo"] }
```

Comment: I'll adjust my answer to the object one :)